# What function or set of functions will yield the highest median of the final values combined?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, median, piecewise

Currently I'm working on an investment experiment and it goes as follows:

```
initializeMoney := (totalMoney = 10);

returnedMoney[w_] := 
Module[{x}, (x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1.1, 1]]; 
If[x < 0, x = 0]; If[(1 < x) && (x < 1.7), x = 1.1]; w*x)]

investStep[tot_] := 
If[(tot < .01) || (tot < myWager[tot]), 0, 
tot - myWager[tot] + returnedMoney[myWager[tot]]]

Clear[myWager];
myWager[totalMoney_] := ???
Piecewise[{{totalMoney/2, totalMoney <= 20}, {2, totalMoney > 20}}];

initializeMoney;
accountBalances = NestList[investStep, totalMoney, 100];
accountBalances[[-1]]
ListPlot[accountBalances]
```

My goal is to have the median of all the final values (after the 5th block of code is ran more than 500 times) as large as possible. Currently I have two problems: I'm not sure of what function will give me a large (above 50) final median value and how to calculate a median of my final values.

Currently the function I have chosen is (since the code remains the same except for the change in myWager, I will only include the changes I made in myWager):

```
Clear[myWager];
myWager[totalMoney_] := 
Piecewise[{{totalMoney/2, totalMoney <= 20}, {2, totalMoney > 20}}];]
```

Example Output with this function (it changes each time its ran):

[image]

So ,as a summary,
I would like to know what function/set of functions (piecewise) will allow me to have the highest (or greater than 50) median value of the final points on the graph (after being computed a total of 100 times)?

Also, how can I compute the median values of the end values (after being computed 500 times)?

Comment: This is not really a programming question suitable for this site is it?  maybe math.stackexchange.com ?